# How to override version to master using Bower?

Tags: angularjs, git, bower

In my app is using [`froala/angular-froala`](https://github.com/froala/angular-froala) plugin which requires [`froala/wysiwyg-editor`](https://github.com/froala/wysiwyg-editor) plugin.

So I've included all as usual, but I need change version from 1.2.6 to latest commit from master branch, and I do so:

```
"overrides": {
    "angular-froala": {
      "main": [
        "src/angular-froala.js",
        "src/froala-sanitize.js"
      ],
      "dependencies": {
        "FroalaWysiwygEditor": "master",
        "angular": "~1.2.22"
      }
    },
    "FroalaWysiwygEditor": {
      "version": "master",
      "main": [
        "css/froala_editor.min.css",
      ]
    }
  }
```

but why it didn't work? Why it is still using 1.2.6 (latest release version)? How to specify to use latest commit and override?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Update:** Why do you need to change the version of a dependency's dependency? In this case `froala/angular-froala`'s has defined its own dependencies, since it needs those to build.

If you change the dependencies of a package, you do not own, you might actually break the build process. Instead of trying to override this, you can do 2 things:

1. Propose an change to froala to update their `bower.json` on the master branch - *very unlikely*.
2. Fork [froala/angular-froala](https://github.com/froala/angular-froala), update the dependencies in the `bower.json` and add your fork as a dependency of your current project.

#### Get the latest version for a dependency

To get the latest commit from a specific branch or commit via bower, use a dependency like this where the string after the hashtag is either the branch name or the git commits SHA:

```
"dependencies": {
  ...
  "angular-froala": "git://github.com/froala/angular-froala.git#master"
  ...
}
```

You can also install it that way:

```
bower install --save git://github.com/froala/angular-froala.git#master
```

Comment: note: `angular-froala` - i do not need this master
in angular-froala dependency is plugin `"FroalaWysiwygEditor": "1.2.6"` and this plugin in my main bower file i must somehow override to use master. also: 
i use jenkins builder, and i could not install nothing in command-line way

Comment: @brabertaser1992 Since `froala/angular-froala` is also on `1.2.6` I kinda mixed up which one you actually wanted to override. See update.

Comment: jfyi: there is important bug fix which is not in release packeage